# Async functions in C# using

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the 'async' and 'await' keywords in VS C# 2010 Express but i can't seem to use this keyword. However, when I use this keyword in VS C# 2012 Professional, it can be used. Is there a special thing that I must download to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`async`/`await` feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx) was introduced in C# 5, which isn't supported by VS 2010. While the Community Technology Previews extended VS2010, I would *strongly* advise you to use the release version of VS 2012 instead of pre-releases. The CTPs had a few bugs, and in general it's not a good idea to use pre-release features when the RTM version is available.

Note that this *isn't* an Express vs Professional issue - if you upgrade from VS C# 2010 Express to [VS C# 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/express) it'll work fine.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I downloaded the VS C# 2012 Express but it requires Windows 8 to install. Is it a better idea to use delegate to do async task or the new await/async functions to do async task?

Comment: Minor clarification on naming; what used to be C# Express no longer exists; there is "... for Web", "... for Windows Desktop", "... for Windows 8", etc - and the "C# Express" maps most closely to "... for Windows Desktop". The 2012 version of "... for Windows Desktop" *is not available yet*.

Comment: @user1334774 see my comment above; it depends entirely on what you are trying to develop. The "... for Windows Desktop" version should be out pretty soon.

Comment: I am basically trying to asynchronously do some tasks like take a photo every hour using a kinect camera. Problem with doing it normally is that it freezes the display and I don't want that.

Comment: @user1334774 to be honest, I meant more "a windows exe", "a console exe", "an ASP.NET MVC site", etc...

Answer (score 1):

Yes; for "Express", what you need would be one of the products in the "Visual Studio Express 2012" range; of this, "... for Web" and "... for Windows 8" are available for download, but "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop" is not yet available.

That keyword only exists in the C# 5 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Its a new feature in 2012 and you cant use it in vs 2010.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed

**Visual Studio Async CTP (Version 3)**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983

and for more info
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127291/C-5-0-vNext-New-Asynchronous-Pattern

Comment: I tried this but it seems that my VS is not SP1 so I can't install it.